# USB device detected by Linux system but unusable with “no medium found” error

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning

Today I experienced a strange problem with my main USB key, and I hope there is a way to extract some data from it. On a Linux system, the USB was working, and after a while it turned to read-only mode. So I unmounted and wasn't able to mount it again.

When I plug the USB I see in the dmesg outout:

```
[  130.015152] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  148.668176] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  148.778233] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0c76, idProduct=0005
[  148.778237] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  148.778240] usb 2-1.1: Product: USB Mass Storage
[  148.778242] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: GENERIC 
[  148.778786] usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  148.778997] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[  149.805608] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     GENERIC  USB Mass Storage 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4 CCS
[  149.806163] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  149.808241] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

The lsusb command shows it as Transcend Flash Disk:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05c6:9204 Qualcomm, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0c76:0005 JMTek, LLC. Transcend Flash disk
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 17ef:480f Lenovo Integrated Webcam [R5U877]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and lsscsi shows it attached as id 4:

```
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      SanDisk SDSSDA24 30RL  /dev/sda 
[1:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  Optiarc  DVD RW AD-7930H  1.D0  /dev/sr0 
[4:0:0:0]    disk    GENERIC  USB Mass Storage 1.00  /dev/sdb
```

and the device shows up in /dev as block device but without partitions:

````
% ls -l /dev/sdb* /dev/disk/by-id/usb-GENERIC_USB_Mass_Storage-0:0 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     9 ott 23 14:52 /dev/disk/by-id/usb-GENERIC_USB_Mass_Storage-0:0 -> ../../sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 ott 23 14:52 /dev/sdb

Now, whatever I try to execute on the device I got a Medium not found or cannot open file error:

% sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No medium found


% sudo testdisk /dev/sdb
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Unable to open file or device /dev/sdb: No medium found
```

% sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/tmp/disk.img
dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': No medium found

% sudo gpart /dev/sdb

*** Fatal error: open(/dev/sdb): No medium found.
````

**I suspect the partition table has gone**, is there any chance I can get data out of the device?

**update**: I've noted that the disk is not listed under `/dev/disk/by-uuid` while it has links to `/dev/disk/by-id` and friends. This confirms the main problem is that the storage seems to be inactive while the onboard controller is active (guessing).

Comment: Becoming read-only is the first sign of an imminent failure. That was the time to backup. Now the chances are slim to none.

Comment: I've seen several times devices going to read-only mode because of a problem, but never related to an hardware failure, that's why it did not alarmed me too much. However, now I would like how to mark the device dead or try to resume it.